# Editing the underbar on a tab in Android

Tags: android

Hey guys I am newer to Android development and I am trying to to figure out how to edit the underbar that is on the tabs when one is selected.  I have this:

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.test.tabbar.style</item>
```

Which points here:

```
    <style name="Theme.test.tabbar.style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>
```

This works great except the `android:actionBarItemBackground` So I was wondering what do I need to point to in order to edit the active bar that shows underneath a tab you are active on?

David

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom theme using this online services and then aplly the theme (remember to copy all the resources in your project!)

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: how do you want to modify it? because the theme use three different version of the tab, just change the assets!, check the teme created using the online creator for an axample.

Comment: I just want to know if I can modify it with what I have up above by adding something of sort.

Comment: I tried to do it several time without success, so I don't think so, it worked following my suggestion. I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but I coulnd' find anything